# Cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone

Tags: c++, overloading

I am reading "Effective C++" and trying to compile this example from rule 3:

```
class TextBlock
{
public:
    const char& operator[](size_t position) const
    {
        return text[position];
    }
    char& operator[](size_t position) const
    {
        return const_cast<char&>(
            static_cast<const TextBlock&>(*this)
            [position]
        );
    }
private:
    string text;
};
```

This must describe how to prevent code duplication; to not write the same code to return a non-const result. I am using VS2012. However I am getting an error. I heard heard that overloaded functions cannot have different return types, but after seeing this I don't know what to think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the book says

```
const char& operator[](size_t position) const
char& operator[](size_t position)
```

not

```
const char& operator[](size_t position) const
char& operator[](size_t position) const  <--- extra const here
```

cv-qualifiers are part of a function's signature, return types are not.

Comment: isn't it also bad practice to return a reference to a char in a `string`? Seems like heap corruption waiting to happen

Comment: @tenfour isn't that what `std::string::operator[]` does?

Comment: @tenfour It may be bad practice from a design standpoint, but where does the heap corruption come in?

Answer (score 3):

As noted already by others, the problem is that you inadvertently added a `const`.

However, more important is that the example you give, from “Effective C++” teaches Bad Things™.

The problem that it deals with is not a problem, and the solution, expressing a non-`const` method in terms of a `const` method, via casts, is an abomination.

At the same time the real problems (such as ease of debugging, checking argument values, definitions before use for readability) are not dealt with.

Here's better and shorter code:

```
using Index = ptrdiff_t;

class TextBlock
{
private:
    std::string text;

public:
    auto operator[]( Index const i ) const
        -> char const&
    { return text[i]; }

    auto operator[]( Index const i )
        -> char&
    { return text[i]; }
};
```

---

For the case where you don't have a convenient already-`const`-paired underlying representation you can use this support machinery:

```
template< class A, class B >
struct With_const_as_T_ { using T = typename std::remove_const<B>::type; };

template< class A, class B >
struct With_const_as_T_< A const, B > { using T = B const; };

template< class A, class B >
using With_const_as_ = typename With_const_as_T_<A, B>::T;
```

… to express both non-`const` and `const` in terms of a template function, like this:

```
class TextBlock
{
private:
    std::string text;

    template< class Self >
    static auto at( Self& self, Index const i )
        -> With_const_as_<Self, char>&
    { return self.text[i]; }

public:
    auto operator[]( Index const i ) const
        -> char const&
    { return at( *this, i ); }

    auto operator[]( Index const i )
        -> char&
    { return at( *this, i ); }      // Look, no casts!
};
```

Comment: It is a very good idea to take the common code into one function, and avoid such ugly cast. However, wouldn't it better to do it a bit differently? Deciphering posted example is not that easy.

Comment: One more question. Will my code be a suitable solution if it contains much more actions than return the pointer?

Comment: @BЈовић: instead of computing the constness each of non-`const` and `const` member function can specify the complete result type, including its `const`-ness or not. this may be clearer, and so might save time on maintenance, but at the same time it's an extra degree of freedom which means it opens the doors for more bugs, which might cost time on maintenance. i like the above because it communicates the intent (which must just be inferred with completely specified result type each call), but personal preference differs. :-)

Comment: @Anton: in the end it's a matter of personal preference. but i think the shorter the code, e.g. just a single indexing expression as above, the less problematic it is to just repeat it. conversely, the longer and more intricate it is, the stronger is the case for factoring that code out in a separate function, to have just a single point of maintenance. just my 2c. others might disagree. :-)